# How to test flask-okta integration?

Tags: python, flask, okta, openid-connect, webtest

I have implemented okta integration in flask using oidc.

```
@route(“/index”)
@oidc.require_login
def index():
    return “ok”
```

I wanted to write integration test using webtest but instead of 200 getting 302 as oidc is redirecting to okta url.

How can in bypass authentication during test cases exexution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require login always checks if the oidc_id_token is exists and not expired. We can manually set for the test environment.

```
oidc.set_id_token_cookie({‘exp’:unixtime})
```